# How to use xmlrpc on odoo with a linux server

Tags: odoo

I want to add some customers and companies with xmlrpc to **odoo v8**.
I searched google but I don't find the right answer. 
I don't know where to put it, in witch folder, and I don't know how to start this.

Thanks for the help.

the democode i take from this [one](http://www.firstclasscomputerconsulting.com/OpenERP/OpenERP70Videos/tabid/145/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/2/Import-data-into-OpenERP-7-using-XML-RPC.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XMLRPC script can be anywhere, it doesn't need to be installed as an odoo module.

It is just a python script that you can run in your machine and it uploads the data to your server using the remote service interface. For that you need to point the right server url, as running it pointing to localhost would expect you to run the script in the same place where odoo is installed.

For building scripts or manage the data remotely without using the web interface, i recommend: http://erppeek.readthedocs.org/en/latest/